# d3 - Graph Network Node Link Spacing

Tags: css, d3.js, graph

So I am working with a d3 network graph and can't figure out how to get more spacing between my nodes and links. `margin` and `padding` are ineffective and those are the main spacing functions in css. The jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zwntgrnu/34/). The code is below:

```
   <script>
    var network = {
            "nodes":[
              {"name":"Sensor Operater","group":1},
              {"name":"Linguist","group":2},
              {"name":"Report Writer","group":3},
              {"name":"Mission Manager","group":4},
              {"name":"Shift Supervisor","group":5},
              {"name":"Geo-location","group":6},
              {"name":"COMINT (Internal)","group":7},
              {"name":"COMINT (External)","group":8},
              {"name":"ELINT","group":9}

            ],
             "links":[
             {"source":6,"target":0,"weight":1},
              {"source":6,"target":1,"weight":1},
              {"source":6,"target":2,"weight":1},
              {"source":6,"target":3,"weight":1},
              {"source":6,"target":4,"weight":1},
              {"source":7,"target":2,"weight":1},
              {"source":7,"target":3,"weight":1},
              {"source":5,"target":0,"weight":1},
              {"source":5,"target":2,"weight":1},
              {"source":8,"target":2,"weight":1}

            ]
          }

var width = 960,
    height = 500

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.05)
    .distance(100)
    .charge(-100)
    .size([width, height]);

  force
      .nodes(network.nodes)
      .links(network.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(network.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.weight); });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(network.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r","5");

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

});
</script>
<style>
        .link {
     stroke: #ccc;
      margin:100px;
    }

    .node text {
    stroke:#333;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:100px;
    }

    .node circle{
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width:3px;
    fill:#555;
    margin:100px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should change `distance` method of your `force`:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.05)
    .distance(100) // <== !!!
    .charge(-100)
    .size([width, height]);
```

I modified your example and add a range slider, try to change it and you will see that spacing between nodes will be changed.

I update `distance` method after slider value changing and restart force simulation:

```
var rangeSlider = document.getElementById('myRange');

rangeSlider.addEventListener('change', function(event,a,b) {
    force.distance(event.target.value).start();
});
```

[image]
Try it in action with the demo below:

```js
var network = {
            "nodes":[
              {"name":"Sensor Operater","group":1},
              {"name":"Linguist","group":2},
              {"name":"Report Writer","group":3},
              {"name":"Mission Manager","group":4},
              {"name":"Shift Supervisor","group":5},
              {"name":"Geo-location","group":6},
              {"name":"COMINT (Internal)","group":7},
              {"name":"COMINT (External)","group":8},
              {"name":"ELINT","group":9}

            ],
             "links":[
             {"source":6,"target":0,"weight":1},
              {"source":6,"target":1,"weight":1},
              {"source":6,"target":2,"weight":1},
              {"source":6,"target":3,"weight":1},
              {"source":6,"target":4,"weight":1},
              {"source":7,"target":2,"weight":1},
              {"source":7,"target":3,"weight":1},
              {"source":5,"target":0,"weight":1},
              {"source":5,"target":2,"weight":1},
              {"source":8,"target":2,"weight":1}
              
            ]
          }

var width = 960,
    height = 500

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var rangeSlider = document.getElementById('myRange');
rangeSlider.addEventListener('change', function(event,a,b) {
 force.distance(event.target.value).start();
})
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.05)
    .distance(rangeSlider.value)
    .charge(-100)
    .size([width, height]);

  force
      .nodes(network.nodes)
      .links(network.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(network.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.weight); });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(network.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r","5");

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

});
```

```css
.link {
 stroke: #ccc;
  margin:100px;
}

.node text {
stroke:#333;
cursor:pointer;
margin:100px;
}

.node circle{
stroke: steelblue;
stroke-width:3px;
fill:#555;
margin:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<h1>
 Hello Network
</h1>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="20" max="500" value="100" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
</html>
```

Actually, other params like `charge` and `gravity` also affect on the nodes position, you can play with them and find optimal for your case.